# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4':Can't use this module

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Hey guys I'm new in Python.I'm using Python 3.6.4 (64-bit) and was installing modules.I was successfully able to download pandas and matplotlib but I don't know why I can't import bs4.

[image: Check the image here]

Please help and please tell what to do.
I'm new so please ignore my mistakes or tell me how to correct it.

Comment: `pip freeze`. Do you have it installed?

Comment: yes I've installed freeze but still no help.

Comment: You've installed freeze? Interesting

Comment: It still gives me that same error of no module found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**first install this from python executable file:-**

```
import pip
pip.main(["install","bs4"])
```

Comment: First i uninstalled bs4 and then again installed it using your comment and it worked. Thank you!. 